# How to select a folder and get folder path in grails?

Tags: grails

I need to select a folder form disk and view all the files in it.

How do I retrieve a selected folder path and how do I preview a selected file using grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code snippet will list all files under a directory

```
File dir = new File("PATH_TO_DIRECTORY")
dir.eachFile{ File f ->
   println f.absolutePath
}
```